# Como escapar o SqlDataSource.FilterExpression?

Tags: c#, webforms

Tenho uma função que adiciona um filtro ao `SqlDataSource`.  Essa expressão contém um `LIKE` na consulta. Porém, se a pessoa coloca um caractere como `'`, acaba acontecendo um erro (o que evidencia o SQL Injection).

```
string cliente = TB_Cliente.Text;

string retorno = "CodOrdemServico = CodOrdemServico ";

if (cliente.Length > 0)
{
   retorno += String.Format("AND Cliente LIKE '%{0}%'", cliente);
}

DS_Grid.FilterExpression = retorno;
```

Como posso escapar o `LIKE` acima?

Comment: o teu `DS_Grid` é um SqlDataSource?

Comment: Bobby Tables manda lembranças

Comment: Sim, @PabloTondolodeVargas

Comment: @Maniero me deprimo vendo tantas perguntas com SQL Injection, o pior que ainda ensinam em faculdade usando concatenação de strings.

Comment: @Maniero esse sistema não foi feito por mim. Estou dando manutenção :\... Tô com vergonha de usar esse Web Forms :|

Comment: Veja isto: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt50s8kz.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parâmetros na *query*.

```
DS_Grid.FilterExpression = "CodOrdemServico = CodOrdemServico AND Cliente LIKE '%{0}%'";
DS_Grid.FilterParameter.Add(new ControlParameter("Cliente", "TB_Cliente", "Text"));
```